# git maintaining two versions

Tags: git

I have a GIT repo that has all files checked in, now I want to publish a couple files of the application to it's own repo for specific developers to work on that particular piece and not see the rest of unrelevant code. 
How should I set this up to maintain some kind of sync between the full repo and the partial repo?

Comment: Maybe a submodule would work? http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: Maybe try something with submodule http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule

Comment: thanks! that's not bad but it kind of is not ideal as it forces you to have all the files under one directory

Comment: found something that seems relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories